# odbc connection only working once?

Tags: php, oracle, xampp, odbc

I'm running the following PHP script to query an ODBC database:

```
<?php

$dsn = "ODBCconnection";
$db_user = "user";
$db_pass = "pass"; 

date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

$conn = odbc_connect($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);

if (!$conn)
{
    exit("connection failed: " . $conn);
}
$query = "SELECT COUNT(column) as count FROM table WHERE criteria";

$test = odbc_do($conn, $query);

$count = odbc_result($test, "count");
echo "The count is: $count";

odbc_close($conn);
?>
```

The problem is not the query or the PHP that I can tell, it works exactly the way I want it to when I run it the first time it comes back with:

```
The count is: 750
```

However if I load the page again, it says:

```
Warning: odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error: Failed to fetch error message, SQL state HY000 in SQLConnect in C:\xampp\htdocs\mailtest\scripts\testscript.php on line 11
connection failed:
```

If I load it again from that page, it just hangs up and times out after my PHP timeout expires. The only way to stop it is to stop and restart Apache, and then it acts the same way; works the first time, says it can't connect the 2nd, then just runs until it times out the 3rd.

I'm using "Oracle in OraClient 10g_home2" ODBC driver and running XAMPP 1.7.4. I've never run into something quite like this, it's like it just gives up after the first go, anyone ever seen this happen and know how to fix it?

Comment: What is the error message in the webserver logs? I suggest you start there.

Comment: the error in the apache error log is the same:

    [Thu Mar 27 17:00:25 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  odbc_connect() [<a href='function.odbc-connect'>function.odbc-connect</a>]: SQL error: Failed to fetch error message, SQL state HY000 in SQLConnect in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mailtest\\scripts\\testscript.php on line 9

Comment: Is it possible for you to put a [logoff trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/triggers.htm#i6061) on the database? This might give you further clues to the erratic behavior.